# Function name for square brackets creating list

Tags: python

Apologies for the simple question - I've spent a while trying to answer it.

When `[]` is used for indexing, Python calls the function `__getitem__`. What function does Python call when `[]` is used to create a list?

Comment: Lists specified with list literals are created directly by the Python interpreter. No Python API is exposed for it.

Comment: This might be useful: https://towardsdatascience.com/no-and-list-are-different-in-python-8940530168b0. See the section "A Breakdown Investigation with Bytecode"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, Python is an interpreter and these brackets are interpreted, without any function or whatever. `__getitem__` just pushes variable into raw interpreter.